# Change Typegoose collection name after initialize

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am using typegoose to create models. During creation of model, I found that it is possible to provide collection name. But once it is assigned, I am not able to find way to modify it.

```
export const MyModel: ModelType<MyModel> = new MyModel().setModelForClass(MyModel, {
    existingMongoose: mongoose,
    schemaOptions: {collection: 'my_collection_name'}
});
```

So in above `MyModel`, I want to change collection name where I am importing.

How can I change a collection name in model? Or am I only left with the option of creating this model where I want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I just had to make function of exported object. So I changed it to below, so that I can pass collectionName where I am consuming this model.

```
const DocumentFieldBooleanValueModel = (collectionName: string) : ReturnModelType<typeof DocumentFieldBooleanValue, BeAnObject> => {
  return getModelForClass(DocumentFieldBooleanValue, {
    schemaOptions: { collection: collectionName },
  });
};

export { DocumentFieldBooleanValueModel };
```

So now above exported model function I can use as below.

```
DocumentFieldBooleanValueModel('MyCustomCollectionName')
```

And it will give same typegoose model.